# Laravel 5: Class 'HTML' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm just getting started with Laravel. I'm in a controller method and I say:

```
return \View::make('scrape', $data);
```

Then in scrape.blade.php I have:

```
@extends('layouts.master');
```

Finally, in layouts/master.blade.php I have:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

And that where things seem to fall apart and I get:

FatalErrorException in 002eb18bb71fd3ec1de058967b799d49 line 6:
Class 'HTML' not found

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cann't you even search a little bit? The answer is so simple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching on google I found [this](http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5)

"By default in Laravel 5.0, Html and Form are not embedded anymore."

You need to add [this](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html) package to you application.

Comment: I did google, but my terms clearly weren't as good as your's. ;) Thx. That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Please use above links and last change `HTML` to `Html`.

**eg**:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

**to**

```
{{ Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}.
```

its working.