# HTML Class not found Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to migrate from Laravel 4 to 5 and my HTML class is not found I have modified the composer file to require `"illuminate/html": "~5.0"` in the providers section of app.php I have

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

and in aliases I have

```
'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
```

but still class HTML is not found any ideas? I have run composer update and dumpautoload just incase but to no avail. Thanks I also have use HTML import statement to cover all bases.

here is my code

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "chumper/datatable": "dev-develop",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/Http/Controllers" ,
             "app/Models"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

app.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => 'http://localhost',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

    'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => 'daily',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
         'Chumper\Datatable\DatatableServiceProvider',
          'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',


        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
        'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
        'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
        'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',

        'Datatable' => 'Chumper\Datatable\Facades\DatatableFacade',

        'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
    'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',


    ],

];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Class 'HTML' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087145/laravel-5-class-html-not-found)

Comment: @watcher thanks but even having followed those steps it still does not work

Comment: @AshleyWrench thanks but this does not make a difference in my case

Comment: did you change your forms to `{!! Form::open() !!}` instead of `{{ Form::open() }}`

Comment: `illuminate/html` is deprecated, use [this](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)

Comment: @lukasgeiter I have added the collectives illuminate package as per your info but it makes no difference ?

Comment: @RichardHewitt Yes this was a suggestion unrelated to your actual problem.

Comment: @lukasgeiter ok point noted thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the upgrade guide: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade

> If you're using Form or HTML helpers, you will see an error stating class 'Form' not found or class 'Html' not found. The Form and HTML helpers have been deprecated in Laravel 5.0; however, there are community-driven replacements such as those maintained by the Laravel Collective.

Link to Laravel Collective: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

After that you should have no trouble using your HTML helpers from L4 again

Comment: thanks I have subsequently switched from illuminate to the collectives version as per the official upgrade guide but this makes no difference I have include HTML also incase it was a namespacing issue thanks

Comment: the answer was actually staring me in the face all along the Alias calls for Html not HTML